# Chalk objects: 3D Printed or Molds?

Tags: molds

I am thinking about making something from chalk. But can chalk be printed into shapes directly or is it better to shape it with printed molds? What kind of material would be suitable for a mold for the chalk so I can ensure the mold releases after the chalk solution cures?

Comment: Asking for "recommendations" don't make particular good SE questions as it can be read as "*what is the best solution for ...*". You should only ask practical, reasonably scoped, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Please help us help you by updating the question to include what you already found about *chalk* printing and ask a specific question on release agents of such printing techniques. Are you e.g. hinting on printing with chalk containing filament called LAYBRICK?

Comment: Have you considered printing your mold in a flexible TPE or TPU?

Answer (score 1):

Chalk, as a ceramic substance, could be printed with a paste printer and if the substance can hold its shape during drying for a couple of hours.

It might be easier to use a flexible filament like TPE or TPU to print a mold in which the paste can cure slowly to a point it can be safely removed. These filaments make release easier as one can flex them away from the printed object.

Another option could be vapor smoothed ABS and a tapered shape so that the object has no undercuts and easy paths only. If one adds a pusher rod place, which is closed by a plug during casting the chalk and can remove from the back after casting, removal gets easier as air can flow in from the back through the removed plug. It can also be used to use a pen or similar obect to gently release the item with light taps.